# Are wildcard generics really needed?

Tags: java, generics

for example:

```
    public String add(Set<?> t){
    ...;
    }



    public <T> String add(Set<T> t){
    ...;
    }
```

The first uses wildcard generics; the second is the normal form of a generic method.
What's the difference?

In what situation do we need wildcard generics, not the normal form of generics?

Comment: It depends on your implementation based on situation.

Comment: No, we don't ever really need a wildcard.  It's just a readability thing to stop us from having a truck load of type parameters, each used just once.

Comment: @DavidWallace: It's not true that we don't every need a wildcard. For example, a `List<List<?>>` is a list which can simultaneously hold lists of different things in it (you can add `List<A>` and `List<B>` into it; but cannot put non`List`s into it). You cannot express this without wildcards, unless perhaps by using raw types. A `List<List<E>>` for any `E` can only hold one kind of list inside it: `List<E>`.

Comment: Wow.  After a lot of thinking about this, I agree.  You, @newacct are right, and I was wrong.  I take back my earlier comment.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a situation where wildcards are required. This method takes a `List<List<?>>`, which is a list of lists. The method can add lists of different component types into it:

```
public void foo(List<List<?>> t) {
    t.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    t.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
}
```

You cannot do this using generic type parameters without wildcards. For example, the following does not work:

```
public <T> void foo(List<List<T>> t) {
    t.add(new ArrayList<String>()); // does not compile
    t.add(new ArrayList<Integer>()); // does not compile
}
```

Comment: +1 IMO nested wildcards should have had a different symbol like `*` since their meaning is different. But return types with top-level wildcards like from `Class.forName` are a great example of them being necessary.

Answer (score 11):

Since support for generics was added, using a parameterized type without providing a type parameter usually causes a compiler warning. On the other hand, there are situations where you don't care at all what the type parameter is (i.e. you don't use the type anywhere) or, even worse, you might not know what `T` is at all, and using `<?>` lets you express just that without causing a compiler warning.

Possible use case for the "don't care" case (very simple for brevity, but you get the idea):

```
public void clearList(List<?> list) {
    list.clear();
}
```

An example for the "don't know" case: an actual method signature from `Class` class:

```
static Class<?> forName(String className);
```

Here the method returns an object of some `Class` type. `Class` is generic but of course you don't know the type because it depends on the `className` parameter which is resolved at runtime. So you can't put `T` here since `T` is not known at compile time (even for a particular call site), and using just `Class` without type parameter would be a bad practice and cause a compiler warning.

Comment: But in that last case, you could write `static <T> Class<T> forName(String className)` and it would be OK.  There is no case when you actually **need** `<?>`.

Comment: @DavidWallace: Those two are completely different. `Class<?> forName(String className);` returns a `Class` of unknown parameter. `<T> Class<T> forName(String className);` returns a `Class` of whatever parameter the caller wants (without knowing what that parameter is). That is obviously impossible to implement safely, unless it always returns `null`.

Answer (score 1):

The wildcard form is when you don't mind what types of objects you are handling.

The generics form allows you to add contraints on the type of objects handled.

An example use case could be the following :
a generic repository with add/update/remove methods, you define common behavior using the generic type :

```
public class Repository<T>{
 public void add(T t){...}
 public void update(T t){...}
 public void remove(T t){...}
}
```

Then to make a repository for `Apple` and `Banana` you just extend this class and replace T with the real type :

```
public class AppleRepo extends Repository<Apple> {}
public class BananaRepo extends Repository<Banana> {}
```

If the generic Repository was declared as `Repository<?>`, it would not be good because it is not restricted to Banana, and you would not be able to use `Banana` specific methods inside it without casting objects;

Also the generics allow you to express further constraints, for example

```
Repository<T extends Fruit>
```

allows you to restrict the generic repository class to fruits. And you will be able to make calls to `Fruit` methods in its code.

Comment: Sure, but this doesn't answer the question.  The question is what situation would _require_ the wildcard; in other words, is there something that we can do with wildcards, for which the other syntax won't work.

Answer (score 0):

There's not difference in calling the methods.

In the second method (`add(Set<T>)`) you can create variables of type `T`:

```
public <T> String add(Set<T> t){
    T item = t.iterator().next();
    //....
}
```

That gives you some additional type checking. 
In the first method you're left with using `Object`.

Comment: Sure, but this doesn't answer the question.  The question is what situation would _require_ the wildcard; in other words, is there something that we can do with wildcards, for which the other syntax won't work.